# CCTransitions with Spritebuilder - Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I am looking at the various transitions between `CCScenes` using `Spritebuilder`. Currently I can do a fade transition using

```
CCScene *gameplayScene = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"kitchen"];
CCTransition *crossFade = [CCTransition transitionCrossFadeWithDuration:0.6];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:gameplayScene withTransition:crossFade];
```

However standard transitions using Cocos2d do not seem to work with SpriteBuilder (or I am missing something!)

I looked at [This Website tutorial](http://www.pawapps.com/2011/07/30/tutorial-transitions-in-cocos2d/) which provided the code below. However it I cannot get it working with `Spritebuilder`

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionCrossFade transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:[NewScene scene]]];
```

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. Your first code fragment should work, so what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: sorry. What I meant is how to do other transitions as I cannot find anything on how to do it with SpriteBuilder. The tutorial linked above has various transitions but I cannot apply them when using SpriteBuilder

Comment: type CCTransition tran.. in Xcode and you'll get completion suggestions for all the other transitions. And check the cocos2d api reference.

Comment: my issue is that when I include a CCTransition it says `no known class...`

Comment: again, type this in xcode and you will get code completion suggestions: [CCTransition tran

Comment: There is only one CCTransition class now Look it up in the cocos2d api reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CCScene *gameplayScene = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"kitchen"];
CCTransition *crossFade = [CCTransition CCTransitionSplitRowsWithDuration:0.6];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:gameplayScene withTransition:crossFade];
```

Replace `CCTransitionSplitRows` with the transition you want. Keep the `WithDuration:0.6`

Comment: My issue is that when I include a CCTransition it says `no known class...`

Comment: Are you sure you installed cocos2d correctly? Do you have cocos2d 3?